# Zend framework 2 accessing global config in model class

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-config

I have a model class which does not extend any core Zend module . This model was imported from my previous Zend framework 1 application . I am able to call its methods by converting it to namespace . The problem what I have is in reading global configuration in side the methods defined .

In case of controller I was able to access global configuration using below code

```
 $config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('config'); 

// This gives a union of global configuration along with module configuration .
```

But what should we do to access configuration in side a model class . 
Below is how my model class is

```
<?php
namespace test\Http; 

class Request
{

    protected $client;

    public function abc( $c)
    {
        return $something;
    } 


    ......

}
```

I am new to Zend framework 2 please kindly suggest any method to achieve this .

In the above description model means ( MVC model class ) which has some business logic in it .

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "model" here? Entity? You probably shouldn't do that if that's the question. Consider that you can reach the global config wherever you have a reference to the service locator...

Comment: @Ocramius Thanks for responding to this , I have a model class ( just a class which has business logic )

Comment: So is it a service? Or just an entity containing data + some logic?

Comment: @Ocramius , Just an entity ,  I dont know what do you mean by entity , But As per my understanding Its an independent business class

Comment: See section "building blocks of DDD" in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design for definitions of Entity and Service ;)

Comment: Check this [solution][1]. You have both the solutions that I can think of.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770966/service-locator-in-zend-framework-2

Comment: @Ocramius I don't need to extend Zend FORM or table because I am not using them is there a Zend Module that I can extend , with out extending If I cant implement I guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you build your service (your code looks like a service) you will probably instantiate it in a service factory (in this case I've put it in the module config):

```
class MyModule
{
    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'my_request_object' => function (
                    \Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface $sl
                ) {
                    $config = $sl->get('config'); 

                    return new \GaGooGl\Http\Request($config);
                },
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

This way, you are injecting the config object directly in its consumer (without having a reference to the service locator in the consumer)

Another way is to implement `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface` in your `GaGooGl\Http\Request`. I [personally discourage it](http://ocramius.github.com/blog/zf2-and-symfony-service-proxies-with-doctrine-proxies/), but this basically allows you to have your `Request` object keep a reference to the service locator internally, therefore making it possible to retrieve the `config` service at runtime.

Comment: Do we need to define this in module.php file

Comment: How to get the config object with in the model class actually I agree you are saying to return config object .

Comment: You cannot have the config object without having access to the service locator. Either pass the config object in the factory (that closure I wrote above) to your `Request` object, or pass the `$sl` to the `Request` object (so that then the `Request` object can access it to get the `'config'` service)

Comment: I don't need to extend Zend FORM or AbstractTableGatewa because I am not using them is there a Zend Module that I can extend , with out extending  I cant implement I guess it throws an error ,

Comment: You are wrong this will return module configuration , not global configuration , I am not getting global configuration .

Comment: This is the globally merged config

Answer (score 1):

simplest way to do this

```
$config = new \Zend\Config\Config( include APPLICATION_PATH.'/config/autoload/global.php' );
```

Comment: I would definitely call this a *hack*.

Comment: I would say a working hack, isn't it ? Maybe `include_once` and not `include` could be better. And maybe using the factory to load the configuration file could be even better. @see https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.config.factory.html

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770966/service-locator-in-zend-framework-2). It has two solutions. One is implementing a Service locator aware interface. Another is to inject the service manager into your model. For both, you need to instantiate your model object through the service manager.