# How do I use the serviceLocator outside of the controller

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

How do I use the Zend Framework Service Locator in a Model?  I have a class that I would like to use the a Table Gateway Model in.  I have followed the Album example and would like to access the table outside of the controller.  However if I copy and paste the code from the controller into the class I need it I get an error (undefined method :getServiceLocator()).  How do I use this 'class'  outside of the controller?

In the end I would like to access the functions in the " class AlbumTable" in something other then the controller (in this case another class).  Thanks.

```
class Calendar implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface{ 

    protected $serviceLocator;

public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
{
    $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
}

public function getServiceLocator()
{
    return $this->serviceLocator;
}
/*
 * Create Calendar Sync Table
 */
 public function getCalendarSyncTable()
 {
     if (!$this->calendarSyncTable) {
         $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
         $this->calendarSyncTable = $sm->get('Pro\Model\CalendarSync\CalendarSyncTable');
     }
     return $this->calendarSyncTable;  
 }
```

Needed to change how I called it in the controller to

```
$calendar = $this->getServiceLocator()>get('Pro\Model\GoogleCalendar\Calendar');
```

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770966/service-locator-in-zend-framework-2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use ServiceLocator in any class, just implement `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface`. For example:

```
class SomeClass implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{
    protected $serviceLocator;

    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
    }

    public function getServiceLocator()
    {
        return $this->serviceLocator;
    }
```

ZendFramework2 will automaticaly inject instance of ServiceLocator to your class.
Read more about ServiceManager [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.service-manager.quick-start.html)

Comment: I'm getting a null value when I var dump service manager.  I have posted my code above.  Is there an additional step I am missing?

Comment: How do you call `Calendar`? If you write just `new Calendar()`, then yes, `$this->serviceLocator` will be null. You need to add your `Calendar` to ServiceManager config, like `'invokables' => array('Calendar' => 'Application\Service\Calendar')`, then this magic would work. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12793595/1129939) for more details

Comment: Does it go in this array?  To this point I have only used the module.conig for routing and controller.  'controllers' => array(
         'invokables' => array(  'Pro\Model\GoogleCalendar\Calendar' => 'Pro\Model\GoogleCalendar\Calendar')

Comment: In side this array? 'service_manager' => array(
        'abstract_factories' => array( 'Pro\Model\GoogleCalendar\Calendar' => 'Pro\Model\GoogleCalendar\Calendar))

Comment: Yes, you should use `service_manager` key. Check examples [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.service-manager.quick-start.html#examples)

Comment: I feel like I am close but still getting null.  I have tried setting up as you did above and also tried the below (how it was configured in another stack overflow post)    'service_manager' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
             'Pro\Model\GoogleCalendar\Calendar' =>  'Pro\Model\GoogleCalendar\Calendar',
        ),
    ),

Comment: Can you add example of using `Calendar` class to the first post? Do you call it from controller, or another class? I think the problem is in the way you use it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73675/discussion-between-matt-and-rodin-vasiliy).

Comment: I call it in the controller
$calendar = new Calendar();

Comment: Final decision after discussion: not to use `new Calendar()`, use `$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Pro\Model\GoogleCalendar\Calendar')` (works in controllers)